# javafx Tableview ordered by date

Tags: java, sorting, javafx, tableview

At the moment I have a tableview showing data. The items in this data include a Repeat value (daily, monthly).

```
TableView

Item1Name | Item1Repeat
Item2Name | Item2Repeat
Item3Name | Item3Repeat
```

What I would like to achieve is to have an overview of the month with the items ordered by date. An item with Repeat daily will be shown under each day, while the item with repeat monthly will only be shown once.

```
Day x
ItemName1
ItemName2

Day x + 1
ItemName2
ItemName3
Day ...
```

My question is:
Which kind of javafx UI Control would be fit to order the data in as I described.
I was hoping there could be one fitting container to achieve this. The other solution would be to build separate table for each day, but this doesn't sound very effective.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A [`TreeView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html) would seem to fit this nicely, or a [`TreeTableView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html) if your Items have multiple columns (multiple, additional to the repeat frequency) and you are using Java 8.

Comment: The problem would be that the root element would be of the type date, and the children would be of the type String. As far is I know, The TreeView requires that the children added to a parent have to be of the same type.

Comment: Yes, that's kind of a pain, though obviously you can make it work with a `TreeView<Object>`. I've often been in the situation where I thought `TreeView<S>` should have a `TreeItem<S,T> root`, where `TreeItem<S,T>` has  `S getValue()` and `<U> ObservableList<TreeItem<T,U>> getChildren()`. But I guess they figured it made the API too complex.